# Point location in 3D convex polyhydron

Tags: computational-geometry

Let P be a 3D convex polyhedron with n vertices.
1. Given an algorithm that takes an arbitrary point q as input, how can I decide in O(n) time whether q is inside or outside the convex polyhedron?
2. Can I do some processing to make it O(logn)?

Comment: I would imagine the time for most algorithms would be bound to the number of faces, not vertices. Do you have the faces, how are they defined?

Answer (score 1):

For (1), if you have a convex polyhedron with n vertices then you have also O(n) faces. One could triangulate each face and in total it would still be O(n) triangles. Now take the query point q and check on which side of a triangle q lies. This check takes O(1) for one triangle, thus O(n) for all triangles. 
EDIT: The O(n) faces define O(n) planes. Just check if q lies on the same side for all planes.

For (2), (I did not find source for this but it seem reasonable) one could project the polyhedron P as P' onto a plane. P' can be seen as two separate planar graphs, one graph U' for the upper part of the polyhedron and the second graph L' for the lower part. In total there are O(n) faces in L' and U'. Now one can preprocess L' and U' via [Kirkpatrick optimal planar subdivision](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=902351) algorithm. (Other sources for it: [1](https://www.cosy.sbg.ac.at/~held/teaching/compgeo/cg_print.pdf) and [2](http://www.iitg.ernet.in/rinkulu/compgeom/slides/triangrefine.pdf)) This enables O(log n) point in PSLG (planar straight line graph) checks.

Now using the query point q and projecting it to the same plane with the same projection one can look up the face of L' and U' it lies in in O(log n) time. In 3D each face lies in exactly one plane. Now we check on which side q lies in 3D an know if q is inside the polyhedron.

Comment: How to check on which side of a triangle q lies?

Comment: As mentioned in the EDIT: A triangle or face of the polyhedron lies in exactly one plane. Just check on which side of the plane q lies. As in caculate the signed point to plane distance, sign already gives you the side. If you want to check triangles. A few determinates should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for (2) will be spacial subdivision of the polyhedron into *slubs* - pyramids with their vertex in the polyhedron centroid and polyhedron faces as their bases. Number of such slabs is `O(n)`. You can build a binary space partitioning tree ([BSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)), consisting of these slubs (probably divided into sub-slubs) - if it's balanced, then the point location will work in `O(logn)` time.

Of course, it will make sense, if you need to call the point location function many times - because the pre-processing step here will take `O(n)` time (or more).

Comment: If you consider the directions from the centroid, they are described by two angles. How do you sort on two parameters ? How do you arrange a binary search tree ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust - I didn't want to get into details, because it's well-known method, please see Wiki article for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning. Also, the OP could use existing libraries instead of inventing a bike - CGAL and others. That's why my answer was so brief

Comment: A binary search tree and a binary space partitioning tree are two very different things. Your text is misleading. I was right not to understand.